# Interactive Grid Control

Tags: c++, opencv, vtk, itk, cimg

I need to code a C++ application that allows the user to edit a Grid that has been created. This grid will allow the user to subdivide an image in blocks.

[image]

I'm familiar with opencv, Itk, Cimg and VTK libraries, but I don't know if those libraries allow to do that. Is there any solution?

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Comment: Well that is the problem, i dont know from where i should start. I dont know if those libraries allow to do that. I did search for some exampels that i can use it, but i can't find any thing.

Comment: will that grid be regular? axis aligned? or curved like in your drawing?

Comment: curved like the drawing. I find that vtk smartpointer class is a good lead. I search how to use it to do what i want.

Comment: If those libraries allow to draw a mesh then they fit you

Comment: ITK certainly has tools to compute B-Spline curves and use them to transform images. I don't know what to recommend for the interaction part.